# add styles if custom header was included

Tags: conditional-tags, headers

I have template which includes(`get_header("modern");`) `header-modern.php`, i need to add styles(in `functions.php`) if included this header, how i can do this ?

`if(is_page_template('header-modern.php')){ wp_enqueue_style('landing-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/navbar.css'); }` i need correct condition.

Comment: Hi Ivan Karaman, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: @kraftner Hi, `if(is_page_template('header-modern.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('landing-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/navbar.css');
    }` i need correct condition.

Comment: (Great tip for the future as you're new here (and welcome by the way ;): If you add what you've tried from the very beginning you prove that you're not just offloading your work to others but actually tried, but hit a wall. This will usually vastly improve the motivation for people to help you!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_header` has an action hook called, (surprise!) `get_header` which gets a single parameter - the name of the header file. So what we do is check that name and if it matches our name we add a style. So something like this:

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'wpse_260353_add_css_for_header' );

function wpse_260353_add_css_for_header( $name ){
   if( 'modern' === $name ){
      wp_enqueue_style('landing-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/navbar.css');
   }
}
```